# QuickSort over a field of an Object

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, quicksort

i have to do a QuickSort to create an Array of "Stones"my question is: i wanna make the QuickSort only over the "ValueySize" field witch is the result of "Value / Size" is there any way to  get a sorted array of stones by valueYSize?

Thanks in advance ;)

public class Stone implements Comparable{

```
private float[] value;
private float[] size;
private float[] valueYSize;
```

}

Comment: Do you mean to have an array of stones (like you say in your question) or an array of values inside the class Stone (as written in your code)?

Comment: If you mean to have a collection of Stoned, you need to implement the compareTo method (Comparable interface), then call Collections.sort on your collection

Comment: i was mistaken, i want an array of stones, sorry for that, i think i fixed it by the way, one of this answers works!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sort method from the Arrays class:

```
float[] valueYSize       = //some operation......
float[] sortedValueYSize = Arrays.sort(valueYSize);
```

Comment: maybe i'm a little stupid today.... or maybe i didn't explain me properly. if y use an array of Stones in other class, how can i make the sort, if i want that in my Stones[] all the objects be sorted by valueYSize?

Comment: @Santanor I must have misunderstood. If that is what you want to do, you need to define the `compareTo()` method that comes from implementing `Comparable`. Then use `Arrays.sort()` on your array of `Stone` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [Arrays#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Answer (score 0):

If your class implements Comparable, you need to override the compareTo method in your class - when you do, return the difference between the valueYSize of the 2 compared objects.